# Access to fetch is blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome-extension, cors, github-api

I am trying to send a PUT request to the GitHub API to upload a file to a repository. The following code generates the CORS policy error.

```
             fetch(url, {
                method: 'PUT',
                headers:{
                  Authorization: "token TOKEN_CODE",
                  message: "test123",
                  content: base64data,
                  sha: file_sha
                }
              })
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(data => console.log(data))
```

The code is for a chrome extension.
Upon searching, I got to know that adding `'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*'` to the header field should resolve the issue but it doesn't seem to work in my case.
I also tried adding "https://api.github.com/*" to the permissions list in my chrome extension but that doesn't work either.

Comment: The access control headers need to be on the GitHub side, not the request side. Also, it's surprising that a Chrome extension would encounter a CORS error, but I'm not a Chrome extension expert.

Comment: If you added permissions for this domain in your manifest, requests should work from inside the background script. It won't work from a content script which is injected into the page, though. Where is yours located?

Comment: I see mine is inside a content script.

Comment: Then, you could either use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/messaging/) between your scripts to tell the background one to make the request for you, or let the content script do the request, and intercept the response in the background script to alter the `Access-Control-Allow-x` headers returned by the server (I see that's what [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en) is doing in their code)